# How to get the row top 1 in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have an issue with Spark Streaming (Spark 2.2.1). I am developing a real time pipeline where first I get data from Kafka, second join the result with another table, then send the Dataframe to a ALS model (Spark ML) and it return a streaming Dataframe with one additional column predit. The problem is when I tried to get the row with the highest score, I couldn't find a way to resolve it.

I tried:

1. Apply SQL functions like `Limit`, `Take`, `sort`
2. `dense_rank()` function
3. search in StackOverflow

I read [Unsupported Operations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#operations-on-streaming-dataframesdatasets) but doesn't seem to be much there.

Additional with the highest score I would send to a Kafka queue

My code is as follows:

```
val result = lines.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
.select(from_json($"value", mySchema).as("data"))
//.select("data.*")
.selectExpr("cast(data.largo as int) as largo","cast(data.stock as int) as stock","data.verificavalormax","data.codbc","data.ide","data.timestamp_cli","data.tef_cli","data.nombre","data.descripcion","data.porcentaje","data.fechainicio","data.fechafin","data.descripcioncompleta","data.direccion","data.coordenadax","data.coordenaday","data.razon_social","data.segmento_app","data.categoria","data.subcategoria")
result.printSchema()

val model = ALSModel.load("ALSParaTiDos")

val fullPredictions = model.transform(result)

//fullPredictions is a streaming dataframe with a extra column "prediction", here i need the code to get the first row

val query = fullPredictions.writeStream.format("console").outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).option("truncate", "false").start()
   query.awaitTermination()
```

**Update**

Maybe I was not clear, so I'm attaching an image with my problem. Also I wrote a more simple code to complement it: https://gist.github.com/.../9193c8a983c9007e8a1b6ec280d8df25
detailing what i need. Please I will appreciate any help :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Use stream-stream inner joins (Spark 2.3.0) or use `memory` sink (or a Hive table) for a temporary storage.

I think that the following sentence describes your case very well:

> The problem is when I tried to get the row with the highest score, I couldn't find a way to resolve it.

Machine learning aside as it gives you a streaming Dataset with predictions so focusing on finding a maximum value in a column in a streaming Dataset is the real case here.

The first step is to calculate the max value as follows (copied directly from your code):

```
streaming.groupBy("idCustomer").agg(max("score") as "maxscore")
```

With that, you have two streaming Datasets that you can join [as of Spark 2.3.0](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-stream-joins) (that has been released few days ago):

> In Spark 2.3, we have added support for stream-stream joins, that is, you can join two streaming Datasets/DataFrames.
>
> Inner joins on any kind of columns along with any kind of join conditions are supported.

Inner join the streaming Datasets and you're done.

Comment: That is a solution, but my environment has Spark 2.2.1 so I could not join between 2 streams. I was thinking in two options first write “fullPreditions” in Hive table and immediately read it, filter and put in Kafka. My second options is to figure out how to solve it in DStream/rdd. I don’t know if you recommend another option or one of them would solve the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"my environment has Spark 2.2.1"_? What's the environment?

Comment: You could assemble the app with Spark 2.3 using [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and forget what you've got installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Implement a function that extract the max value of the column and then filter your dataframe with the max

```
def getDataFrameMaxRow(df:DataFrame , col:String):DataFrame = {
 // get the maximum value
 val list_prediction = df.select(col).toJSON.rdd
         .collect()
         .toList
         .map { x =>  gson.fromJson[JsonObject](x, classOf[JsonObject])}
         .map { x => x.get(col).getAsString.toInt}
 val max = getMaxFromList(list_prediction)

 // filter dataframe by the maximum value
 val df_filtered = df.filter(df(col) === max.toString())

 return df_filtered
}


def getMaxFromList(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
 case List(x: Int) => x
 case x :: y :: rest => getMaxFromList( (if (x > y) x else y) :: rest )
}
```

And in the body of your code add:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.google.gson.Gson
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val fullPredictions = model.transform(result)
val df_with_row_max = getDataFrameMaxRow(fullPredictions, "prediction")
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: Is this going to work with a **streaming** Dataset? I doubt that given `.rdd.collect()` which are unsupported in Spark "Streams".